# schengen visa refused from french embassy pakistan

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, schengen-visas

my relative and I, both currently unemployed but starting school/careers soon, had decided to make a short term trip to Europe before we get on to our lives.

I previously have one visa refusal and one removal order from canada. Basically I was in canada, working, when my then visa got refused and by law I had 90 days to restore my status. I stupidly applied for incorrect visa, which I found about much later on ( probably should have consulted with some lawyer first ) so when the restore application got refused, that automatically meant i have to leave the country so that counted as ' removal '. During this time I obeyed all laws and regulations and conditions of my stay and did not do anything illegal. anyways i left the country within 30 days. I show all of this in my application in form of explanation letter. I have applied for PR for canada as well, however since at the time of my schengen visa i had not officially submitted all documents, i couldnt show them any prove of that so i left that as i did not have any acknowledgement letter of that.

My relative also has one visa refusal from canada. he once applied for study permit and even got call for medical. due to family emergency, he decided not to continue the application. unknowingly to him, if u dont respond to request for medical, couple of weeks later that automatically counts as refusal.

I am in between jobs so I put occupation as unemployed/travelling.
My relative is joining university in canada in May for which he has applied for visa. He is just waiting for his visa for that so he put occupation student.

Anyway we submitted our application with A to Z all documents at french embassy in pakistan. We indicate our refusals, submit refusal letters, explaantion letters, my brother shows his canadian university offer letter that he plans to leave schengen visa because he has to go to university, all that stuff.

today we got sad news that our visas have been refused for the following reason:

Your intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the visa applied for could not be ascertained.

Is our current situation most likely reasons for visa refusal that we had past visa refusals from canada? was it a mistake to be truthful about that in our applciations? 
Is there a way we can ask them to give us specific reasons as to why our visa got refused?

We just wanted to enjoy have a good summer time in europe.

we just want to know what exactly prompted them to refuse our visas.

Comment: All of the things you mentioned are factors in the refusal. Quite importantly making a mistake in your Canada visa application still puts you in violation of the law. It was your responsibility to get it right and you failed to do that. This indicates to visa offices that you don't understand what you are signing and so can't be trusted to abide by the rules.

Comment: Why did you submit your previous refusals and removal when not even asked about it? Main reason you were refused it because of your employment status.

Comment: https://pk.ambafrance.org/Short-Stay-less-than-3-months,2437#tourism

Comment: it said on the application form :( have u been refused visa before? should i have said no?  but thats the confusing part. if someone is rich but is not working at the moment or cant find job and he HAS the money to travel then what is the problem? i dont get it

Comment: The Schengen application form does not ask about previous refusals. https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/IMG/pdf/Formulaire_SCH_eng.pdf You're not working in Pakistan. You previously worked in Canada. They suspect you might go to France and stay there indefinitely. Your ties to Pakistan aren't strong enough. It's not about being rich

Answer (score 2):

It might have been your previous refusal, your current situation, or most likely a combination of both. And possibly your source of funds.

- You have demonstrated that you could not be trusted to understand and follow the Canadian rules. That means the visa officials will be extra vigilant regarding your new application.
- A typical tourist or business traveler has a steady job with steady income. Some tourists are young people funded by their parents or other relatives, but then the parents need a steady income to explain where the money came from.

It probably was a **good** idea to tell the truth. In a few years, when you have a steady job, you might make a new application for a Schengen visa. If the Schengen officials had decided that you *lied* now, they wouldn't believe you in the future when your circumstances look much better.

Comment: The Schengen application form does not ask about previous refusals. To volunteer negative information without being asked for it was a mistake on the OP'S part.

Comment: thank u. yes its not on the application form. it was actually on another form given to us when we went to collect the application package. should i have indicated no then? wouldnt that have been lying?

Comment: @JIM in that case you should have reconsidered your itinerary. Generally speaking, the French and Germans are known to be notorious with their visas in Pakistan. It's probably too late now but you could have spent most of your holiday in Italy. You would have had a better chance.